# Счетчик побед и поражений в Телеграм боте

Tags: python, telebot

Пытался сделать телеграм бот 'Камень, Ножницы, Бумага'. Все работает кроме кнопки 'Стоп'. По задумке она должна выводить число побед и поражений но выводит просто нули которые были обьявлены изначально. Буду очень благодарен если укажете на все ошибки в коде и как можно было сделать все проще :)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Камень")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Ножницы")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Бумага')
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Стоп')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def game(message):
    t_list = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага']
    count_win = 0
    count_lose = 0
    random_answer = random.choice(t_list)
    if(message.text == 'Камень'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{random_answer}')
        if message.text == random_answer:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text= f'Ничья')
        elif random_answer == 'Бумага':
            count_lose +=1
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text= f'Ты проиграл :)')
        elif random_answer == 'Ножницы':
            count_win +=1
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text= f'ПОБЕЕЕЕЕДАААА!!')
    if(message.text == 'Ножницы'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{random_answer}')
        if message.text == random_answer:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ничья')
        elif random_answer == 'Камень':
            count_lose += 1
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ты проиграл :)')
        elif random_answer == 'Бумага':
            count_win += 1
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'ПОБЕЕЕЕЕДАААА!!')
    if (message.text == 'Бумага'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{random_answer}')
        if message.text == random_answer:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ничья')
        elif random_answer == 'Ножницы':
            count_lose += 1
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ты проиграл :)')
        elif random_answer == 'Камень':
            count_win += 1
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'ПОБЕЕЕЕЕДАААА!!')
    if(message.text == 'Стоп'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text= f'Побед:{count_win}\n Проиграшей:{count_lose}')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)`
```

Comment: Вы объявили `count_win` и `count_lose` только внутри одной функции, вы не записываете их ни в какое внешнее хранилище и не считываете ни из какого внешнего хранилища (хотя бы глобальных переменных), вот они и создаются в начале работы функции и уничтожаются в конце работы функции

Comment: Кроме того, если вы всё-таки будете делать какое-то внешнее хранилище, не забывайте, что для разных пользователей должны быть раздельные счётчики

Answer (score 0):

Штош.

1. Не берите условие в скобки просто так, даже PyCharm ругается.
2. Делайте аннотацию типа аргумента функции (локальная переменная), в данном случае `def game(message):` сделать `def game(message: types.Message):` Это даст вам подсказки при вводе.
3. ReplyButton можно создавать более лаконично. Вместо

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Камень")
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Ножницы")
btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Бумага')
btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Стоп')
markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
```

допустим так

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
markup.add("Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага", "Стоп")
```

4. Доп. к пункту 3. Для красоты сделаем вот так, чтобы кнопка "стоп" была ниже.

```
markup.add("Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага").add("Стоп")
```

5. Не пишите просто так фильтр для хендлера `content_types=['text']` он стоит по умолчанию.
6. Создайте словарь с юзерами. Пусть он будет глобальным. При старте, сделаем создание юзера.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    users[message.from_user.id] = {'state': 'game'}
    
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага").add("Стоп")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет", reply_markup=markup)
```

И ваши локальные переменные `count_win` `count_lose` меняете на

```
if users[message.from_user.id].get("count_win") is None: 
    users[message.from_user.id]["count_win"] = 0
    users[message.from_user.id]["count_lose"] = 0
```

7. Для кнопки стоп сделаем отдельный хендлер.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Стоп")
def stop_game(message: types.Message):
    # Сброс стейта. Так бот не будет реагировать на камень ножницы бумагу
    users[message.from_user.id]['state'] = ''
    wins = users[message.chat.id].get("count_win", 0)
    loses = users[message.chat.id].get("count_lose", 0)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Побед:{wins}\n Проигрышей:{loses}', reply_markup=markup)
```

8. Меняем логику победитель-проигравший и вместо кучи ифов делаем словарь где ключ это выбор игрока, а значение это тот выбор бота, при котором игрок побеждает

```
results = {
    "Камень": "Ножницы",
    "Ножницы": "Бумага",
    "Бумага": "Камень"


if message.text == random_answer:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ничья')

elif results[message.text] == random_answer:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'ПОБЕЕЕЕЕДАААА!!')
    users[message.from_user.id]["count_win"] += 1
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'ПОРАЖЕНИЕ')
    users[message.from_user.id]["count_lose"] += 1
```

9. Ну и я пока это писал, некоторые вещи немного менял. Где-то добавил условие, чтобы кнопка реагировала только при определенном стейте, где-то ещё что-то. Короче результат.

```
import random

from telebot import TeleBot, types

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

users = {}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    # Если такой юзер уже есть, то просто игнор
    # иначе создаст для него словарь со стейтом
    users.setdefault(message.from_user.id, {'state': 'game'})
    # по факту команда старт единственный способ начать игру, 
    # после кнопки стоп, так что придется сделать  вот так
    # чтобы стейт поменялся
    users[message.from_user.id]['state'] = 'game'
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага").add("Стоп")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(
    func=lambda message: message.text == "Стоп" and users.get(message.from_user.id, {}).get('state') == 'game')
def stop_game(message: types.Message):
    # Сброс стейта. Так бот не будет реагировать на камень ножницы бумагу
    users[message.from_user.id]['state'] = ''
    wins = users[message.chat.id].get("count_win", 0)
    loses = users[message.chat.id].get("count_lose", 0)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Побед:{wins}\nПроигрышей:{loses}', reply_markup=markup)


# Фильтр таков. Хендлер тригерится только на слова камень ножницы бумага и только если у юзера стейт game
@bot.message_handler(
    func=lambda message: message.text in ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага'] and users.get(message.from_user.id, {}).get(
        'state') == 'game')
def game(message: types.Message):
    t_list = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага']

    if users[message.from_user.id].get("count_win") is None:
        users[message.from_user.id]["count_win"] = 0
        users[message.from_user.id]["count_lose"] = 0

    random_answer = random.choice(t_list)
    results = {
        "Камень": "Ножницы",
        "Ножницы": "Бумага",
        "Бумага": "Камень"
    }

    if message.text == random_answer:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ничья')

    elif results[message.text] == random_answer:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'ПОБЕЕЕЕЕДАААА!!')
        users[message.from_user.id]["count_win"] += 1
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'ПОРАЖЕНИЕ')
        users[message.from_user.id]["count_lose"] += 1


bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Возможно где-то что-то провтыкал, а так вроде работает.
PS. Вообще вместо извращений со словарем, стоит использовать FSM, но в телеботе он мне не понравился. Так что рекомендую айограм, там проще с этим.
Ну и наконец, вы должны понимать что данные будут храниться до первого падения бота. Можете в целом хранить этот словарь users в каком-то файле, но лучше сделать полноценную бд, или как я говорил перейти на айограм там есть возможность использовать mongoDB как быструю память, чтобы не захламлять БД всякими счетчиками поражений.
UPD  Ну и последний редакт. Покажу результат на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]